# Using JUnit, how do I mock this public constructor that calls some protected method?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermockito

In my code, I have lineItems.getList() calling a protected method within that class.

```
public class Itemized {
    List<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();
    public void execute {
        try {
            //Establish some logic here
            Items lineItems= new Items (order1, order2);
            itemList = lineItems.getList();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
          .....
        }
        finally {
            (if itemList !=null && !itemList.isEmpty()) {
                //do something here
        }
```

And here is my test case

```
@Mock
private Items items = Mockito.mock(Items.class);  
@Injectmocks
Itemized itemized;  

@Test
public void testItemized() throws Exception {
    List<String> mockItemList = new ArrayList<String>();
    mockItemList.add("ABC");
    mockItemList.add("DEF");
    PowerMockito.whenNew(Items.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(items);
    PowerMockito.when(items.getList()).thenReturn(mockItemList);
    mockItemList = items.getList();
    itemized.execute();
}
```

When I tried to system.out.println the mockTestList from test case, it returns the list.  However, in my Itemized class, it's always return empty, hence, it never makes it to the finally block.

**UPDATE** Here is the class that I'm trying to mock

```
public class Items {
    private List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
    public List<String> getList() {
        return items;

    .....
    //other protected methods that call addItems
    ......

    private void addItems(String item) {
    items.add(item);
    }
]
```

I'm still fairly new with unit testing so perhaps I incorrectly mocked somewhere along the line.

Comment: I think you should do PowerMockito.when(items.getList()).thenReturn(mockItemList); not PowerMockito.when(items.getErrorList()).thenReturn(mockItemList);

Comment: Thanks, it was a typo and I have updated my question.  However, the issue is still there where my expectedValue (mockItemList) is always empty regardless of what I specified to return mockItemList when call GetList().

Comment: can you provide a full code in github? also I don't think you need mockItemList = items.getList();

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
@Mock
private Items items;  
@Injectmocks
Itemized itemized = new Itemized();  

@Before
public void setup(){
    Mockito.initMocks(this);
}
@Test
public void testItemized() throws Exception {
    List<String> mockItemList = new ArrayList<String>();
    mockItemList.add("ABC");
    mockItemList.add("DEF");
    PowerMockito.whenNew(Items.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(items);
    PowerMockito.when(items.getList()).thenReturn(mockItemList);
    //mockItemList = items.getList();
    itemized.execute();
}
```

if you forget `Mockito.initMocks(this);` that will be the root cause.

Comment: I have updated with the class that I'm trying to mock and I always have Mockito.initMocks(this) in my test case.  Thanks.

Comment: please provide me the code, i will find the root cause for you